# Minimum singular value of sum of rotations

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, reference-request, svd, orthogonal-matrices

Consider orthogonal matrices $Q_1, Q_2 \in \mathbb{R}^{d \times d}$, where
both matrices are [proper rotations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix) of angle $\theta_1, \theta_2$ around different axes. Now, consider the symmetric matrix

$$
A = \frac{Q_1 Q_2 + Q_2^\top Q_1^\top}{2}
$$

> **Question**: is there a nontrivial lower bound for $\sigma_{\min}(A)$ in terms of $\theta_1, \theta_2$?

If $Q_1$ was the trivial rotation, we would have $\sigma_{\min}(A) \geq \cos(\theta_1)$. However, it is unclear to me what happens after composing the two rotations.